# Why timestamp+incrementing mode is actually required in Kafka Connect?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, timestamp, apache-kafka-connect

I was reading about Kafka connect (JDBC source) and I couldn't wrap my head around the actual need of `timestamp+incrementing` mode. If `timestamp` mode can get updates/inserts once we have a `updatedAt` timestamp column which might not necessarily be unique but it will always increase with updates/inserts.

I read somewhere that `timestamp+incrementing` provides a globally unique ID for streaming but I am not really sure how that ID will be used if I am dumping the data into Kafka and then from Kafka to s3. Also I read that due to some `early shutdown` procedure we require `incrementing` column, but again I am not sure if that is some internal kafka connect issue.

Here is the code that I found on github for the implementation of timestamp+incrementing.

```
 protected void timestampIncrementingWhereClause(ExpressionBuilder builder) {
// This version combines two possible conditions. The first checks timestamp == last
// timestamp and incrementing > last incrementing. The timestamp alone would include
// duplicates, but adding the incrementing condition ensures no duplicates, e.g. you would
// get only the row with id = 23:
//  timestamp 1234, id 22 <- last
//  timestamp 1234, id 23
// The second check only uses the timestamp > last timestamp. This covers everything new,
// even if it is an update of the existing row. If we previously had:
//  timestamp 1234, id 22 <- last
// and then these rows were written:
//  timestamp 1235, id 22
//  timestamp 1236, id 23
// We should capture both id = 22 (an update) and id = 23 (a new row)
builder.append(" WHERE ");
coalesceTimestampColumns(builder);
builder.append(" < ? AND ((");
coalesceTimestampColumns(builder);
builder.append(" = ? AND ");
builder.append(incrementingColumn);
builder.append(" > ?");
builder.append(") OR ");
coalesceTimestampColumns(builder);
builder.append(" > ?)");
builder.append(" ORDER BY ");
coalesceTimestampColumns(builder);
builder.append(",");
builder.append(incrementingColumn);
builder.append(" ASC");
```

}

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mode=timestamp+incrementing` is not "required". There are other options.

> read somewhere that...

[The documentation perhaps?](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#jdbc-source-configs) Where you'd also see this mode is not required.

As you found, it is considered a unique ID that prevents reading the same rows upon restarts. It helps determine if there are duplicate timestamps, which ones might have already been read.

S3 is irrelevant to the question or how the JDBC source connector works

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I know it's not required but this mode is considered to be best if we want both updates and inserts. 

I was just curious why they created this mode specifically. So the only reason is duplicate reading of data right in case of restarts?